# ASP.NET - Send value from JavaScript to Sql Server Database

Tags: javascript, sql, asp.net

I am doing a small application with asp.net. I have a JavaScript file that gives me a value which I want to store inside an SQL Server Database but I have no clue how. The values I want to add are response in the code below:

```
function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        console.log('Logged in and Authenticated');
        setELements(true);
        testAPI();
    } else {
        console.log('Not authenticated');
    setELements(false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question has fundamental problems. Firstly, you can not access any DB directly from the Front-end of your application. Your changes to the database are made with your back-end, which here is .Net. If you are using MVC (Model,View,Controller) you can create needed controller and models, then you can make db changes with context of your database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just created the MVC infact. Now, I wanna know how to pass the values.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a Action Method in your asp.net MVC Controller.cs File and call through it by using ajax call.

**ajax call:**

```
jQuery.ajax({
url: 'YourController/Save',
type: "POST",
data: "{'Value' : " + str + "}",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function (data) {
             alert("a");
          },
failure: function (msg) { alert("Sorry!!! "); }
});
```

**Action Method:**

```
public JsonResult Save(string value)

{

return Json("Saved");
}
```

Write your saving code in MVC Action method.